# Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD. HAXM is not installed. Install Intel HAXM for better emulation performance

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, haxm

when I try to run my emulator it's show me HAXM is not install, when I click on the install button, it's show me "Android SDK is up to date.
Running Intel® HAXM installer
Intel HAXM installed successfully!
Done"
after show this message, I try to run My installed ADV, it's again show me Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.
HAXM is not installed.

Install Intel HAXM for better emulation performance."
and it's happen every time and I couldn't run my Emulator, I Reinstall
android Studio but problem not yet gone, how can I solve this.

Comment: Install the newest haxm (HAXM v7.7.0 at github.com/intel/haxm/releases). If any issues will occur during installation, HAXM installer will show a detailed output of what exactly failed. Add a screenshot of these errors tho your question.

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\users {user}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelarated_Execution_Manager and run the installation file located there.